# JQuery: How to activate and deactivate $(document) function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to activate $(document).click function only after some actions and then deactivate after few responses.

Thanks

Comment: So you put it in `if` condition?

Comment: `$(document).off('click')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event listeners using jQuery `on` fn and remove added using `off`:

```
var clickHandler = function() {}

$("btn").on("click", clickHandler);
$("btn").off("click", clickHandler);
```

Here is more info:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: You are welcome